# Check if any date in a range is between another range

Tags: python, django, django-views, date-range, python-datetime

I have the following situation:

This is my `views.py`:

```
def home(request):

    date = datetime.date.today()
    start_week = date - datetime.timedelta(date.weekday() + 1)
    end_week = start_week + datetime.timedelta(6)
    week_tasks = Task.object.filter(owner=request.user, start_date__range=[start_week, end_week])
    context = {}
    context['week_tasks'] = week_tasks
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

This view check if the `start_date` (DateField) is inside the range of the current week. But I have another field on the database, `end_date`, and I want to check if any value of this range is on the current week.

Check the exemple:[image]
Let's supose that the current week is the week of the day 17. With my current view, only the **All Day Event** and **Conference** belong to the week. I need to show that all these events belong to the week.

Obs.: I can't just check if `start_date` and `end_date` are in the week, because I have the situation of the **Long Event**, that starts before the week and ends after.

---

### WORKING:

`views.py`:

```
def home(request):

    date = datetime.date.today()
    if date.isoweekday() == 7:
        date = date + datetime.timedelta(1)
    start_week = date - datetime.timedelta(date.isoweekday())
    end_week = start_week + datetime.timedelta(6)
    week_tasks = Task.object.filter(owner=request.user).exclude(end_date__lt=start_week).exclude(start_date__gt=end_week)
    context = {}
    context['week_tasks'] = week_tasks
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

week window is defined by: week_start, week_end

tasks are defined by: task_start, task_end

task has overlap with week if:

```
task_start < week_end and task_end >= week_start
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I only need to add this logic to my query: `week_tasks = Task.object.exclude(owner=request.user, start_date__gt=end_week).exclude(end_date__lt=start_week)`

Comment: Actualy, I need to make this query: `week_tasks = Task.object.filter(owner=request.user).exclude(end_date__lt=start_week).exclude(start_date__gt=end_week)`. With the another, I was excluding the owner... HAHA =D